# Add exception to regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm using this code I stumbled upon to 'clean up' urls with jquery:

```
.replace(/[^\w ]+/g,'') // and
.replace(/ +/g,'-')
```

The first one removes non alpha-numeric characters, while the second turns spaces into a dash

My question is: Is there a way to exclude a character, in my situation, # , from this first `.replace()` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a standard JavaScript String method, not a jQuery thing. (I hope you don't mind, but I retagged your question accordingly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.replace(/[^\w#\/ ]+/g,'') // and
```

Comment: Also do you know how I would do this with a `/` ?

Comment: THANK YOU!!! so I can keep adding on exceptions like that? This worked. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @iight: `[^...]` construction means "match everything except of what is specified in `...`. In your case `[^\w#\/ ]` - is "match everything except of \w (letters and underscore), # sign, / sign and a space"

Comment: Thank you for the deeper explanation! Do you know what I can search for to learn more about this?

Comment: Or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more info about JS's implementation of regex.